# How to link facebook comments widget to the current url?

Tags: facebook, widget, comments

I've got a bit of a problem with facebook comments box on my website. I can't figue out a way for it to link the comments to the url they are on. For example a fb comment to Post 1 on my site is shared between all of my post wich can be a bit misleading for the users. I post about hundred posts a day (pics mainly), there's no way I can make a new box for each and every one of them.

Here's the piece of code that's troubling me:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="funshit.ru" data-num-posts="5" data-width="530" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

If only there was a way to make it link to the current url the problem'd be solved.

Any help is appreciated m8s.

Comment: if you can use PHP, then something like this... `data-href="http://funshit.ru<?=htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], ENT_QUOTES)?>"`

Comment: Thanks for trying. Didn't help though. Once I put it in it kept sharing the comments with every single post + it started telling "can't get access to [link](http://invalid.invalid/?=htmlspecialchars($_SERVER%5B)"

Answer (score 6):

Because the CMS I was coding in didn't reliably return the current URL and leaving it blank or omitting it failed, I wrote the div tag in Javascript:

```
<script>
document.write("<div class='fb-comments' data-href='" + window.location.href + "' data-num-posts='2' data-width='400'></div>");
</script>
```

Of course, this will include the data in the query string but you should be able to exclude that if that's what you want.

Comment: Simple and awesome. You should also note to put this `<script>` exactly where you want it on your page.

Comment: @MattWay Indeed, I ended up using `document.getElementById('fbComments').innerHTML = "<div class='fb-comments' data-href='" + window.location.href + "' data-num-posts='5' data-width='100%'></div>";`

Answer (score 3):

You can omit `data-href` (or leave it blank) so current URL will be used.

**Update:**
As of Sep 2012 the method above is working only for *first version of the Facebook Comments box*.

To use newer version of Comments social plugin you will need to specify current URL explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but if I do it says that this widget needs an href parameter.

Comment: Just checked, works as expected (both empty or missing `data-href` attribute). Do you speaking about "yellow note" that suggests to specify this attribute, or about some error that appears in "red"?

Comment: @Rimian, it is not (but it warns you about working in compatibility mode).

Answer (score 0):

This one seems to be foolproof and vastly simple:

```js
// In the next line, you must grab the parent element of the div with class fb-comments.

var oComments = document.querySelector("#CONTAINER-OF-COMMENTS-BOX");

oComments.innerHTML = '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.whatever.com/" data-num-posts="NUMBER OF POSTS TO SHOW" data-width="WIDTH OF CONTENT"></div>';

FB.XFBML.parse(oComments);
```

You can alternatively select the parent element with jQuery like so:

```js
var oComments = $(".fb-comments").parent().get(0);
```

Make sure to alter the `data-href` attribute of the `fb-comments div` to change the URL for which the comments are about.  You should also adjust `data-num-posts` for the number of posts to show and `data-width` for the width of the content.  That ought to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Use check below script, which is working for me.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     var postUrl = '<data:post.url/>';
     document.write("<div class="fb-like" data-href='" + postUrl + "' data-layout="standard" data-action="recommend" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>");
</script>
```

Its give link of each post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am a blogger, I Used below script in my blog, which is working for me.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     var postUrl = '<data:post.url/>';
     document.write("<div class="fb-like" data-href='" + postUrl + "' data-layout="standard" data-action="recommend" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>");
</script>
```

Its give link of each post accordingly. It might help full for you also.